# Is it possible to add more metadata to a bitstream in DSpace, like author, publisher etc..?

Tags: metadata, dspace, bitstream

Is it possible to add more metadata to a bit streams in DSpace, like author, publisher etc..?

Comment: Please explain literally what you mean by that "bit streams". You use "bitstream" tag that represent python library for manage binary data. You mean "bitstream" as a batch metadata import via the command line? Do you want to transfer only text metadata (author's name, isbn, doi, publisher, etc.) or binary data (for example a document in pdf)? Thx for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

If we are really talking about `bitstreams` and not `items` the answer is:

**DSpace 6 and prior:**
No. The only metadata you can set for a bitstream in this versions of DSpace is `Filename`, `Description` and information on the file format.

**DSpace 7:**
DSpace 7 allows you to define arbitrary metadata fields on a `bitstream` level, just like you can do on `item` level. In DSpace 7 you define those fields in `submission-forms.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Since DSpace 5 any DSpaceObject can have any metadata attached to it; at least in the sense that you don't have to add additional table columns (all will be stored in metadatavalue table).

So, technically, yes you can add metadata to bitstreams; but the shipped UI's don't expose the functionality, you'd have to add that yourself (or wait for DSpace 7).

Answer (score 1):

A user who has administrative privileges for an Item (usually inherited from its Collection during submission) should be able to browse to the Item and use the "Edit this item" link in the Context menu (on the right side of the page in the XMLUI Mirage theme).

If you need to edit many Items, you may wish to consider the batch metadata editing facility.  See [the DSpace documentation](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC6x/Batch+Metadata+Editing) for details.